# How search data from access database using phone number that without masked

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I have use this (123) 456-7890 format to search data on access database using winforms and my data was saved in same above format but I want do the search throw winform that allow me to enter 1234567890 then give the search result but I can't able to get it from access query

I have tried remove using access format function on my database but it doesn't work and also I have tried mysql replace query still not working.

here is my select query

```
Command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM PersonalINFO  WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + 
   LastName = '" + search_txt.Text + "') OR (EmailAddress = '" + 
   search_txt.Text + "') OR (Home_Tp = '" + search_txt.Text + 
   "') OR (Cell_Tp = '" + search_txt.Text + "') ";
```

How do I able to ignore the brackets and dashes in the phone number mask when searching I can't able to create new row that without mask because my data size  over thousand I have tried remove using access format function on my database but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

storing masked data is not good and it causes complexity hence logical errors  and implementation difficulties. I suggest you to use plain format like `123456789`.

we generally prefer to show masked data inside input field but store it as it is.

---

On the other hand using concatenated strings in query is very bad practice and it is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Instead you need to use [*Parameterized Queries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query)

Comment: I'm using an old data set from the client that I can't able to remove